# trouble showing detail information from PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I followed the Parse Query Table tutorial on Parse to make a table. Everything works accordingly but now I am having trouble trying to figure out how to display detail information for a specific row. All the detail information is saved to the same object in Parse. How would I go about accessing it to display it in a new view when the row is tapped? I tried getting the objectID from the specific object but everything i tried would would not work or wouldn't let me access objectID.

I will provide code/more information if needed to help answer, I don't want to post all the code when not all of it is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your prepareForSegue method? As far as I understand from your explanation, you do not 
set the object which is in table index path. When you segue, you must prepare the view and set the 
necessary objects in order to show the detail of object.Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: I didn't use storyboards for this project, but everything seems to be already loaded into it. I just have no clue where it is being stored. Thanks for the help though!